# FilenameUtils.getExtension comparison returns false

Tags: java, swing, csv, string-comparison, jfilechooser

I am very confused by this comparison with `FilenameUtils.getExtension`.

I have a file chooser `fc` that I want to ensure that the extension is `.csv`.

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
if (fc.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION &&
    fc.getSelectedFile().isFile() &&
    FilenameUtils.getExtension(fc.getSelectedFile().getName()) == "csv") {
    // Do stuff
}
```

After some debugging, I found that the last statement was responsible for not having the if statement executed.

```
FilenameUtils.getExtension(fc.getSelectedFile().getName()) == "csv"
```

However I did many `System.out.println()`s and got that

```
System.out.println(FilenameUtils.getExtension(fc.getSelectedFile().getName()));
```

Prints `csv`. But still returns false when I enter:

```
System.out.println(FilenameUtils.getExtension(fc.getSelectedFile().getName()) == "csv");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Problem your facing is and well known one. You are trying to compare Strings with the ==-operator. Instead of that you should use the [equals-function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) of String.

There is a little difference between you those two ways:
If you want you can read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion) and there answers to see the difference between both.

Applied to that code it should look like that:

```
System.out.println(FilenameUtils.getExtension(fc.getSelectedFile().getName()).equals("csv"));
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 6):

You can't compare the content of Strings with `==`. You'll have to use the `equals(...)` method for that:

```
System.out.println(FilenameUtils.getExtension(fc.getSelectedFile().getName()).equals("csv"));
```